# How to order an Oracle nested table type by index in a query

Tags: oracle, nested

I have an *Oracle* **nested table** type defined as following:

```
create or replace type Varchar2ArrayType as table of varchar2(4000) ;
```

I know how to query a variable of this type but I don't know how to return rows ordered by the index:

```
declare

  arr Varchar2ArrayType := Varchar2ArrayType() ;

begin

  arr.extend(3) ;
  arr(1) := 'ZXC' ;
  arr(2) := 'ASD' ;
  arr(3) := 'GHJ' ;

  for rec in (
    select
      column_value
    from
      table(arr)
    order by
      column_value
  ) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.column_value) ;
  end loop ;

end ;
/
```

In the above PL/SQL block I wish to replace the `order by column_value` clause with an `order by index` clause... Do you know a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old but in case this helps someone else.
You should be able to add rownum in an inline view and order by that column.

```
declare
  arr vc_coll := vc_coll() ;
begin
  arr.extend(3) ;
  arr(1) := 'ZXC' ;
  arr(2) := 'ASD' ;
  arr(3) := 'GHJ' ;

  for rec in (
  select *
    from (
          select
            column_value,
            rownum rnum
          from
            table(arr)
        ) s
    order by rnum
  ) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.column_value || chr(9) || rec.rnum) ;
  end loop ;
end ;
/


ZXC 1
ASD 2
GHJ 3


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by 'return rows', but to loop over them in 'index' order you can loop from 1 to [`count`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CIHGJCHF):

```
declare
  arr Varchar2ArrayType := Varchar2ArrayType() ;
begin
  arr.extend(3) ;
  arr(1) := 'ZXC' ;
  arr(2) := 'ASD' ;
  arr(3) := 'GHJ' ;

  for i in 1..arr.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(arr(i)) ;
  end loop ;
end ;
/

ZXC
ASD
GHJ

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You could also use `for i in arr.first..arr.last loop` here; docs for `first` and `last` are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CIHGFJFA). If you're manipulating (i.e. deleting from) the collection after populating it then you need to  be aware of how those functions behave, as the documentation illustrates.

You can't order using the `select from table` syntax because `arr` is only in-scope within the `table()` function; it is not visible to the `order by` clause and the index value used within the nested table doesn't exist. If you just leave off the `order by` clause then the rows seem to be ordered by the index anyway, but I don't think that's guaranteed.

```
...
  for rec in (select rownum as rn, column_value from table(arr)) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.rn ||':'|| rec.column_value) ;
  end loop ;
...

1:ZXC
2:ASD
3:GHJ
```

You could perhaps use a [pipelined table function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#i52954) to return a record type that includes both the index and value as two columns if that isn't robust enough.

Comment: You're right Alex, I oversimplified my problem... I have to join the nested table with a database table and order the result by the nested table order... that's why I have to use a query.

Comment: @CristianVeronesi - are you stuck with the nested table collection type?

Comment: Thank you Alex, your thoughs are exacly the same as mine: rows seem to be ordered by the index anyway, but I don't think that's guaranteed. I thought about a pipelined table function too, I was just wandering if there is a simpler solution. It seems not.